We destroyed a lich's phylactery right in front of his eyes, what to prepare for?
A lich gave us a task to retrieve his phylactery. When we retrieved it, we went back to the lich, and while giving the phylactery, we got into an argument among ourselves. The cleric just couldn't do it, and for me as druid, the reward was useless (my character hates going to cities and crowds, and the reward was to know a passage into a city so you don't have to pay a toll).
So we, at the last second, while talking to the lich, decided to try destroying the phylactery. Against all odds dispel magic worked, and the DM allowed us to destroy it -- while the cleric was shouting at the lich how much of an abomination he was.
However he also told us we "better prepare" for next session.
I wonder what the difficulty would be, we are a level 8 team, with 4 players, a cleric (twilight), druid (moon), paladin/sorc hybrid (6 paladin, 2 sorcerer) and an artificer. Are we kind of "screwed" if the dm goes for vengeance? Are there options to flee last minute?

I'm a little confused- is this marked opinion-based because OP asked 'screwed?' in addition to how difficult?
I feel that enough detail was given about the circumstances and party composition to give a mechanical answer; knowing a lich is CR21 and that the party is level 8, I would say it's a matter of game math and printed stat block abilities viewed as statistics rather than opinion; arguably the only opinion required is whether or not "screwed" carries enough weight as a word to describe their situation.  For example, at least one character is dying to PW:K if a fight pops off.

While the question could perhaps have been phrased a little more objectively, it seems the fundamental question is "What is the optimal strategy to deal with a lich given this party composition?" That is a tactical and objectively answerable question (And I agree with Nobody the Hobgoblin's answer. Unless the DM is deliberately pulling punches, run.)

@ThomasMarkov Levels and classes are provided, and all the classes provided prepare spells from a full access list- except the sorcadin, whose sorcerer spells and level split we don't know. Equipment would help the question, but plenty of information is given to start with helpful information like "Have the cleric bring death wards and the sorcadin bring counterspells."
Overall, I read the question as "is this fight winnable, and if not what can I do to get away."
Shy of a teleporting magic item not mentioned in OP, was this not asked and answered objectively?

@TheFallen0ne Yeah, I’ve voted to reopen

“Fly, you fools”
Prepare to flee, and hope that not too many of you die while beating your escape. A Lich is a CR 21 monster, worth 33,000 XP. That is four times the XP budget for a deadly encounter of a level 8 party of four. While it is not impossible to survive such odds in some cases (the CRs for higher level play are somewhat inflated and often do not carry their weight), your chances of surviving a fight here are pretty dim.
For example, the only one of you who can counterspell is the Sorcerer, and so can the Lich. That means if its a standard-issue Lich, power word kill will be able to take one of you out, if you don't get away in time. And it probably goes downhill from there. Dominate monster on another spellcaster who could dispel it (if they get lucky), and you're down to 2 vs 2. The lich has nasty legendary actions, too.
So my advice for you is to run and fight another day. According to the XP rules, it takes less than a month of adventuring in-game to get to tier 4 levels where you stand a much better chance, and it is not clear if the Lich can create a new phylactery at all, but if it can, it is probably a long and complicated process, so your risk of being off worse then are very low.
Of course, that may mean the lich is out after you for vengeance, and that are pretty dire prospects, too, but actions have consequences, so you better learn to live with it.
PS. All this assumes your DM is not pulling the punches. And they may. After all, you should not have been able to destroy the phylactery at all to begin with (MM, p. 103)

Destroying a lich's phylactery is no easy task and often requires a special ritual, item, or weapon. Every phylactery is unique, and discovering the key to its
destruction can be a quest in and of itself.

So your DM may likewise decide to make that fight winnable for you somehow. But, if you are not sure they will, flight is by far the safer option here.
The rules do not make it that easy to flee from a fight, so use whatever means you have to get away fast - dimension door, misty step, haste, transforming into a very fast flyer, dash, and go in different directions: the lich, by going after one of you then has to abandon immediate pursuit of the others.

We have a deal with a cr 11 devil, which could be "summoned once", and we have a book containing a portal gate to another side of the world that require a special passphrase to open. Would it be logical for a lich to then "stay behind to build a new phylactery instead of going for vengeance". Going for cold reasoning? That's what twe aimed for.

It wouldn't. If your DM applied cold reasoning, then the high Int lich will figure out it better kills you all now - you actively opposed it and you destroyed its phylactery (and know about that). It should go after you with all its means, scrying etc. to kill you off before you get powerful to become a greater threat - which it also might realize may happen well before it is done making a phylactery. You pulled a career-ending move, better hope your DM is lenient and lets the lich decide you are no threat and putter after making a new phylactery instead, in spite of it.

It‘s like when you piss off a super powerful faction with access to high level assassins - the logical move is to kill y'all. But as a DM, if you have an alternative that with some level of suspending disbelief makes sense, it is often better to go for that than TPK your team of fools. This is all pretty meta but you need to give your DM at least a chance to do that.

@nonymous You got it — thanks for fixing the quote to the correct translation (or rather non-translated original i stead of wrongly backtranslated one).

This is good advice, but would be improved by one ray of hope: The lich presumably doesn't want to die, either, and with its phylactery destroyed there is a chance (however remote) that it might. If the party can demonstrate that it has some ability that they could plausibly use to destroy a lich, the lich is likely to attempt a tactical withdrawl. (That being said, since 5e has very few save-or-die spells that could pose a credible threat and liches have a list of immunities as long as your arm, there's no guarantee the party has such an ability on hand.)

@GMJoe Yes, I agree - this "plausible" alternative is what the DM might opt for if he does not want to grind out the PCs without mercy. And by fleeing instead of forcing the fight, the PCs allow him the room to do so.

We just discovered that the lich was hiding from a group of illithids, I guess we should just let them fight

@paul23  You should take advantage of this mercy and time by running away as fast and as far as you can, in case the lich wins.

You’re not wrong here, but we also have no idea what the DM is planning. This could be part of their story line and we just ruined it by telling them to run.

I’ve downvoted this because it isnt clear there’s a reason the characters would know any of this, so telling OP to play this way is textbook metagaming.

Prepare based on what your characters know.
We can tell you that a Lich is much too hard a fight for your characters, and you, the player, probably already knew that. But the real question you should be asking is ”what does my character know here?” Narratively, it makes the most sense for the characters to prepare in a manner consistent with what they know about the world and the Lich. So viewed this way, you and your companions are the only ones who can answer this question concretely.

I tend to agree, though it might be worth cautioning against "My Guy Syndrome". https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it

@nonymous: I don't see the relevance. My Guy syndrome is almost exclusively about taking disruptive actions based on a chosen motivation/personality for your character. Guiding the set of possible actions based on the information your character could potentially have, rather than out of game knowledge, is a good thing (the alternative is definitionally metagaming); My Guy syndrome is wholly orthogonal.

I'm confused by this answer: the goal is to solve he puzzles and dungeons right? Character knowledge is vast, considering you have often travelled the world for ages and often think of special roles your character would have (IE: our cleric was part of a special forces unit to hunt down undead beings), dwarves and elves live long time and no one wants to play like a child so you are 100+ years old. Because of this inconsistency that I always see in dnd I prefer to ignore that part of the game, and just solve the puzzles like a chess position.

@paul23 Does your character know everything there is to know about liches?
